# ldaps issue while starting up service

Tags: openldap

```
service ldap restart
Stopping slapd:                                            [FAILED]
Checking configuration files for slapd:                    [  OK  ]
Starting slapd: 27861:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:632:Expecting: CERTIFICATE
27861:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:632:Expecting: CERTIFICATE
27861:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:632:Expecting: CERTIFICATE
27861:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:632:Expecting: CERTIFICATE
27861:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:632:Expecting: CERTIFICATE
27861:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:632:Expecting: CERTIFICATE
Enter PEM pass phrase:
```

Not sure why i get these error msgs.

Comment: There is an issue with your certificate.  What format is it in?  What have you changed before the service broke?  Details help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Check your certificate and your private key with `openssl`. Make sure they are in PEM format. PEM is an ASCII armored format (open it in an text editor), and you should see `BEGIN CERTIFICATE` and respectively `BEGIN PRIVATE KEY`.

Answer (score 0):

PEM certificates usually start with:

`-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`  << (5 dashes before and after)

and end with:

`-----END CERTIFICATE-----`  << (5 dashes before and after)

There should be no whitespace before or after the dashes and no carriage return(s) trailing the "END CERTIFICATE" line (openssl doesn't care about the carriage returns when validating a cert but some things do care).

It is not unusual to assume that one should copy everything between the BEGIN and END lines when you actually need to copy everything including the BEGIN and END lines.